# Using arrays as columns with handsontable

Tags: javascript, arrays, handsontable

I'm using [handsontable](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/2.0.0/tutorial-introduction.html) to display data for an application. I want to use arrays as *columns*, which I can't seem to figure out with the documentation. I suppose the best approach would be to use an array of my arrays, but I'm having trouble piecing it together.

Here's the code so far:

```
var data = [
  ["Sale Month", "Usage", "Address", "Tax Assessment", "Loan Amount", "Initial Equity", "Lien Start Date", "Lien Term", "Loan Type", "Square Feet", "Year Build", "Acres"
      , "Beds", "Baths", "Lotsort"]
];

var container = document.getElementById('listview');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true
});
```

I have a set of arrays for each column header. For example, the `saleMonth` array looks like `['01/18, 03/16, 01/12']` and so on. I want to use the indices of each array for entries in the corresponding column.

Here's the current output:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvRtq.jpg)

Please let me know if I can be more clear.

Thanks!

Edit: added a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vipertherapper/rom0c2nt/)

Comment: can you reproduce this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @Taki Yes, added it to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your data structure a little bit: changed `data` to a list of headers (`columns`) and moved your arrays of values into a map (`values`) where the key is the name of the column and the value is the original array

In this way you could elaborate your data to create an array of `rows` in the suitable format

```
var saleMonth = ['01/18', '03/20']
var usageArray = ['Residential', 'Commercial']

var values = {
  'Sale Month': saleMonth,
  'Usage': usageArray
}

var columns = 
  ["Sale Month", "Usage", "Address", "Tax Assessment", "Loan Amount", "Initial Equity", "Lien Start Date", "Lien Term", "Loan Type", "Square Feet", "Year Build", "Acres"      , "Beds", "Baths", "Lotsort"]

;

var rows=[];
var numOfRow
for ( numOfRow = 0; numOfRow < saleMonth.length; numOfRow++ ) {
    rows.push(columns.map((e) => {
    if (e in values) {return values[e][numOfRow]}
    return e;
    }));
}

var container = document.getElementById('listview');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: rows,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true
});
```

You could also set in the `Hansontable` configuration object `colHeaders: columns` to get column titles instead of letters